# Will old cast iron Baseray baseboards work with a steam boiler?

Tags: boiler, baseboard

forgive me if this question is amateurish. We recently removed some old cast iron Baseray baseboards from a house which were being heated with hot water. I'm wondering, can these baseboards be used with a steam boiler?

The baseboards look exactly like this https://www.ebay.com/itm/323735785091

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know if your steam boiler/system is one-pipe or two-pipe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That baseboard radiation will work great on a 2 pipe steam system or a forced hot water heating system but is not recommended for use on a 1 pipe steam system.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!